# inflate a linear layout using layout inflator

Tags: android

I have an xml which consists of two linear layouts. Each linear layout consists a listview. The upper linear layout will occupy entire screen. At bottom I have a label. If I click the label, the second layout should be inflated and display the content. I am able to inflate the layout but it is not displaying any content. Any help please?

```
if (isclicked) {
                        subjectlistview_premium.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);





                        LinearLayout item = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.subjects_linear);
                        View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.subjectlayoutpremium, null);
                        item.addView(child);

                        scroll.post(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                scroll.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_UP);
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        subjectlistview_premium.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        scroll.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                scroll.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
                            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually one constructs a [FrameLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html) and 2 layouts in it. Then you can make visible either the one or the other of those child layouts.

Comment: OnClick, layout should move to top. is this possible?